# How to combine different scopes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, conditional-statements, named-scope

I have the following named scopes in my rails app:

```
  scope :published, :conditions => {:status => 'published'}
  scope :coming_soon, :conditions => {:status => 'coming_soon'}
  scope :in_development, :conditions => {:status => 'in_development'}
  scope :cancelled, :conditions => {:status => 'cancelld'}
```

I'm having trouble writing one that combines "published" and "combing soon." Here's what I've tried.

```
  scope :public, :conditions => {"status == published || status == coming_soon"}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you you want an AND or an OR? IIRC `||` is OR.

Comment: I was confused about that too.  The question said combine (sounds like 'AND', but the code has || which is an `OR`.  They I noticed that we are just looking at one field.  Well a field cannot be two different values at the same time (can't have `x = "A" AND x = "b"`!) so it must be an `OR`, as in: `x = "a" OR x = "b"`

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought -- it had to be OR. But either way, the code below seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 2: `named_scope :public, :status => ['published', 'coming_soon']`
Rails 3: `scope :public, where(:status => ['published', 'coming_soon'])`

Rails will see the array and use the `IN` operator in the sql.

An a note: The other approach (chain existing scopes) of Article.published.coming_soon would NOT work because an Article can't be both of those things at the time time or be a subset of each other.

Another note:   Careful when you want something dependent on a variable parameter.  For example say you wanted "future appointment" for a scheduling system, you might write
[This is **invalid**]

Rails 2: `named_scope :upcoming_appts, :conditions => (['appt_dt > ?', Time.now])`
Rails 3: `scope :upcoming_appts, where(['appt_dt > ?', Time.now])`

However there's a problem:  The `Time.now` will get evaluated *the first time the class is evaluated* **not** when the scope *itself* is evaluated.
To overcome this you use a lambda (silly name but basically means anonymous function - or to put it even simpler 'a function that doesn't actually have a name') as follows:

[This is **valid**]

Rails 2: `named_scope :upcoming_appts, lambda {:conditions => (['appt_dt > ?', Time.now])}`
Rails 3: `scope :upcoming_appts, lambda {where(['appt_dt >= ?', Time.now])}`

This scope will now get evaluated at execution time each time - it is used - so Time.now will be the actual current date-time.

Comment: A nit but you used a double quote at the end of the coming_soon string but started with single. I would change but it is asking for at least six changes...

Comment: I'm getting an error on the comma `SyntaxError: /Users/justin/Code/boxfire/app/models/product.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC
..., :conditions => {"status = ?", ['published', 'coming_soon']}`

Comment: Changed to this: `:status => ['published', 'coming_soon']` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ScottJShea, I fixed it.  And I gave you a +1  SO usually hs a way to reward :)

Comment: Added the rails2 / rails3 versions syntax.

Comment: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) but that's just nit picking :)